# css switching vs. css changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to change the css of a page. I see two ways of doing it :

Using the `Jquery .css` function to change every tag in the html.
example :

```
$("body").css("background : red")
```

Or disabling the current css stylesheet and enable a new one.

example:

```
function switch_style ( css_title )
{
// You may use this script on your site free of charge provided
// you do not remove this notice or the URL below. Script from
// http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml
  var i, link_tag ;
  for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
    i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
    if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
      link_tag[i].title) {
      link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
      if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
        link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which way is the more efficient ?
Or maybe there is better ways ?

Comment: There's a third option: giving the `body` an extra class and using `body.class2` in your CSS instead of using a second stylesheet.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt - Make that an answer.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt You should put this as answer :)

Comment: Okay, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a third option: giving the `body` an extra class and using `body.class2` in your CSS instead of using a second stylesheet.